# What is the in-universe cost of a TIE fighter?

Tags: star-wars

I would like to know how much a TIE-fighter costs, *preferably in credits.*

Comment: About [US$25](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Star-Wars-TIE-Fighter-model/192758261515?hash=item2ce149a70b:g:-xsAAOSw0vJcE9Fy:rk:8:pf:0).

Comment: I need a legitimate answer in star wars and credits. But thanks anyway if I want a model I'll get that lol.

Comment: Hi close voters, how is that too broad? Not saying it absolutely isn't, but a comment clarifying why ithere's too much info about it or something would be nice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [*Star Wars Roleplaying Game Revised Core Rulebook*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Roleplaying_Game_Revised_Core_Rulebook), a standard TIE Fighter costs 60,000 credits new, or 25,000 credits used.

[image]

This was confirmed in the [*Starships of the Galaxy: Saga Edition*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Starships_of_the_Galaxy_(Saga_Edition)) sourcebook.

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of stripping out the (low-value) wikipedia link and replacing it with the (high value) wookieepedia links to the actual books quoted.

Comment: I know it's for an RPG, but I'm impressed that there are enough second-hand TIEs available FOR SALE that there's a consistent value to their 'used' price.

Comment: @Kozaky I feel like there's plenty of haggle room on the used market. I'm not familiar with the game system but I'm sure your CHA (or equivalent) would come into play when dealing with black marketeers and corrupt Seinar officials.

Comment: @Kozaky - Like most military surplus, it's usually cheaper to sell it (and recoup some of the value) than to keep repairing it.

Comment: 25000 credits used? (Looks at wallet). Damn.

Comment: @Valorum, pfft, a TIE fighter that has been repaired more than once should cost more as a super rare, lucky bastard edition model.

Comment: Any idea what 1 Star Wars credit equates to in U.S. dollars?

Comment: The rate of inflation between A Long Time Ago and now is difficult to calculate...

Comment: I find it surprising that a TIE would survive long enough to be available used.

Comment: @Headblender from some guides that I've seen, a credit seems to be very close to a dollar when looking at items that are roughly equivalent in our world and the world far away.